# npx create-react-app my-app ERROR "In most cases you are behind a proxy..."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

Error when using `npx create-react-app my-app`. I'm new in `node` and `react` and I'm trying to create my first react app. I seem to have fairly good internet connection.

I tried `npx create-react-app my-app` 6 times but it's having the same error:

```
user@Acer:~/ReactProjects$ npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in /home/user/ReactProjects/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fplugin-proposal-async-generator-functions: read ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2022-03-06T11_34_36_543Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from /home/user/ReactProjects
Done.
user@Acer:~/ReactProjects$
```

I am running this on `windows 10` `build 19044` using `vscode` with `remote wsl extension` which connects to my `ubuntu-20.04` on `wsl2`.
I want to create my first `react app`.
**What should I do from here?**

Comment: Same thing happened with me but 3rd or 4th time, app is installed. It takes time to creating react app. So, try once more.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes i got same error when not connected with network or poor network connection.

Answer (score 1):

try to update npm using npm install -g npm@latest --force

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me in wsl

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this Error occurred because you are using proxy server to connect internet if so stopping using proxy will solve it but if you want to keep up with proxy
follow this
first clear cache

```
npm cache clear --force
```

second:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

third:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

last:

```
create-react-app appName
```